# Cannot run T4 template in Windows Universal App (Javascript) in VS 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, t4

I added a **T4 template** to a **Windows Universal App (JS)** project and I can't run it. I was expecting the **"Run Custom Tool"** and **"Debug T4 Template"** option when I right click the template file.

When I right click it there is nothing:

[image]

Is there another way to run the template? Do I need to reference something?

Answer (score -1):

What is the need of creating T4 template in universal apps?
Have you tried adding T4 template in VS 2013? It will not give you an option also.